# Improper text appearance in Custom AlertDialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-constraintlayout, layout-inflater

In my code, I'm presenting a custom alert dialog by inflating a layout and set it as the dialog's view.
The problem I'm having is that the text looks OK in the Android Studio's design tool, but at run-time, the dialog becomes smaller and the text takes more lines.
I tried different approaches to fix it, but didn't acquire the wanted result.

For the layout, I'm using constraint layout and the text is `"wrap content"`.

**Here's my code:**

```
    //inflate alert layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connectivity_issue_counter, null);
    //set builder
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setView(view);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

    final AlertDialog alert = dialog.create();
    //define dialog buttons and counter......//
    alert.show();
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/alertBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectivity_issue_title"
        style="@style/customAlertTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:text="@string/connectivity_issue_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/connectivity_issue_wait"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectivity_issue_wait"
        style="@style/customAlertTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/connectivity_issue_wait"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/connectivity_issue_counter_text"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectivity_issue_counter_text"
        style="@style/customAlertTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connectivity_issue_main_text"
        style="@style/customAlertMainText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/connectivity_issue_main_text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/connectivity_issue_title" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/connectivity_isuue_button"
        style="@style/customAlertButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="@string/stop"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline21"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline22"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/connectivity_issue_main_text" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.82" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Another interesting thing** - on a different tablet (both the same model) the dialog looks bigger and wider.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please provide me with your layout code as well?

Comment: updated in the post

Comment: Okay, thanks Itay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Maybe the text is bigger on that phone? I can't see the `customAlertTitle` style, but I suppose the text is on "SP", and these are "DP" but text-size dependent (if the phone is set to show the text on a big font from it's settings tab, it will increase it's size).

Maybe a solution could be to set the sizes to "DP", but you won't let the people change it, so it has counter effects.

Another idea that comes to my mind is that the size of the screen you are previewing on the preview is larger than your phone's screen.

The last thing I would try is to change the 'android.R.id.message' TextView's size by hand after creating the dialog. Once you show it you can access the message's textview by calling for it's id,

```
TextView messageTv = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageTv.setTextSize(X);
```

Edit: Don't mind that last idea, as you are inflating your own layout, maybe you can try to access your id and change it the same way, but with `R.id.connectivity_issue_wait`

Comment: Thanks Davidaz!
the text is really in SP, I'll try changing it to DP.
the preview is in the same size as the tablet.
if the DP thing won't work I will try this approach.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped you! Keep in mind, though, that this is not a good practice, and that even if you set this to DP, there are some phones with custom configuration that can change the size of every detail on the screen. Sometimes it's better to not try to be pixel-perfect but to design a layout that can be well looking on every device!

Answer (score 1):

As Davidaz suggested, I've changed the text size from sp to dp and it helped to solve the problem.